# Causality requirement in JMM

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, concurrency

I am trying to understand causality requirement of JMM. This section of JMM describes it  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.8

What does E means in the causality definition? Does it mean Execution we are trying to justify or the execution to justify the commit from Ci to Ci+1?

Also in the 9 rules of causality definition are for adding an action from A to committed set of action from Ci-1 to Ci or from Ci to Ci+1.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does E means in the causality definition. Does it mean Execution we are trying to justify or the execution to justify the commit from Ci to Ci+1.?

*E* is the execution which causal validity you're trying to determine.

*E<sub>i</sub>* are the well-formed executions, through which you can work with causality without introducing the notion of total time order.

> Also in the 9 rules of causality definition are for adding an action from A to committed set of action from Ci-1 to Ci or from Ci to Ci+1.?

I'm not sure if I understand your question.
My attempt at answering may involve rehashing of stuff that you're not interested of, but please bear with me.

An execution is valid in terms of the causality requirements of the Java Memory Model if all its actions can be *committed* according to the rules in section 17.4.8.

The rules in this section define what can be committed by establishing a rule-set for building up from the empty set of committed actions to eventually the set of all actions of the execution. This is done in a discrete number of steps, and there are consistency rules and invariants for the committed actions at each step and their relation to the committed actions at the previous step in the different executions (*E* vs *E<sub>i</sub>* from above).

As for committing actions according to the last rule (the ninth numbered bullet in section 17.4.8) by definition, each set *C<sub>i</sub>* is a proper subset of *C<sub>i+1</sub>*, so actions are not committed from *C<sub>i</sub>* to *C<sub>i+1</sub>*, but from *A* to *C<sub>i</sub>*.

I've found the following two links the best resources for clearing the mist around causality in JMM:

1. [JMM Causality Test Cases](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/unifiedProposal/testcases.html)
2. [Alexey Shipilev's JMM Pragmatics talk](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/)

**P.S.** For the folks that do not have context about this part of the spec, the main point of section 17.4.8 is to bridge the gap between *happens-before* consistent executions and *SC DRF* (sequentially consistent, data race-free) executions. The difference between these two are the so-called out of thin air values, which the cryptic section 17.4.8 disallows, and which can be pretty awful to reason about if left unchecked.